# Updating rails partial with a collection through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form which allows users to post an update. Once the users post the update I would like the list of updates to refresh. To achieve this I'm using Ajax and jQuery and using Rails. I'm running into trouble while trying to get jquery to render the post feed partial though.

Here's the jquery I'm using

```
$(".microposts").html("<%= j render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>")
```

At the moment, the feed just refreshes and displays nothing. I believe it's due to the way I'm trying to pass the @feed_items. What's the best way to pass that variable?

Someone asked for the controller;

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
before_action :correct_user, only: :destroy

def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to root_url }
            format.js 
        end
    else
        @feed_items = []
        flash[:error] = "Failed to create micropost!"
        render 'static_pages/home'
    end
end

def destroy 
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Micropost deleted!"
        redirect_to root_url    
end

private

    def micropost_params
        params.require(:micropost).permit(:content)
    end

    def correct_user
        @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
        redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

Comment: can you paste also the controller?

Comment: @matanco Added in, I know the controller's working as other elements update when the post is made.

Comment: `@feed_items` is empty no matter what. maybe this cause your problem. i don't see any case you put something into this variable.

Comment: @matanco It's not, it's defined elsewhere by current_user.feed which is
    Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self)
I really think my problem is with how I'm passing the partial render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@feed_items` needs to be defined somewhere **in the controller**. The `@` is a special symbol in Ruby that signifies an *instance variable* of the current class. If you define it somewhere else, it becomes an instance variable of *that* class.

Rails has some special magic that makes the instance variables of the controller available in the view. If it's not an instance variable on the controller, it won't work.

```
def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
        @feed_items = @micropost.do_whatever_to_build_the_feed_items
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to root_url }
            format.js 
        end
    else
        @feed_items = []
        flash[:error] = "Failed to create micropost!"
        render 'static_pages/home'
    end
end
```

Comment: Your explanation made a lot more sense and the mistake was obvious! Thanks a lot!